# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS in a procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @roomPrice DECIMAL(18, 2) = (SELECT TOP(1) r.Price 
    FROM Rooms r
    JOIN Trips t ON t.RoomId = r.Id
    WHERE r.HotelId = @HotelId AND 
     ((@Date NOT BETWEEN t.ArrivalDate AND t.ReturnDate) 
      OR t.CancelDate IS NULL) AND r.Beds >= @People
    ORDER BY r.Price)
```

The error I am receiving is `Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure udf_GetAvailableRoom, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0] Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.` I know that I can't return multiple columns in my subquery, that's why I am taking `TOP(1)`. Can someone explain to me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking away the parentheses from `Top(1)` (see proper syntax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)):

```
DECLARE @roomPrice DECIMAL(18, 2) = (SELECT TOP 1 r.Price 
    FROM Rooms r
    JOIN Trips t ON t.RoomId = r.Id
    WHERE r.HotelId = @HotelId AND 
     ((@Date NOT BETWEEN t.ArrivalDate AND t.ReturnDate) 
      OR t.CancelDate IS NULL) AND r.Beds >= @People
    ORDER BY r.Price)
```